# I am stuck at "not defined" but it looks defined to me

Tags: python, converters

i am stuck. I dont know where i went wrong.

```
def convert_distance(miles):
    km = miles * 1.6  # approximately 1.6 km in 1 mile

my_trip_miles = 55

my_trip_km = km * my_trip_miles

print("The distance in kilometers is " + str(my_trip_km))

round_trip= my_trip_km * 2

print("The round-trip in kilometers is " + str(round_trip))
```

I keep getting "km" is not defined.

Comment: It is defined inside of `convert_distance`, but not outside of it.

Answer (score 3):

You should return the value from your function

```
def convert_distance(miles):
    km = miles * 1.6  # approximately 1.6 km in 1 mile
    return km
```

then assign that to a variable

```
my_trip_km = convert_distance(my_trip_miles)
```